# At Azure Data Collection Rule I can't select source

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have Azure Data Collection Rule, I have Log Analytics WorkSpace, I have Azure Arc, but when I want Select Data Source Destination, I don't see anyone.
[image]

Is somebody who knows where I have error?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I also get "blank" on my data source destination like below***:

[image]

- This issue may occur, if your Log Analytics workspace ***is not in same region***

To confirm this I have created log analytics with different region ***it does not appear in my data source*** destination with central us like below:

[image]

***When I create Log Analytics workspace with same region, I got my data source destination like below:***

[image]

Make sure your log analytic and azure arc in same region.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed the region under the "Basics" tab for my new data collection rule, and was able to see my OMS workspaces again.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it accepts only Microsoft-InsightsMetrics which will be applied by default